# Gettext on php/iis/win7, wrong charset

Tags: php, iis-7.5, gettext

I am refactoring some old app in php 5.2.17 and converting it to UTF-8 charset. App uses gettext, but for some reason, gettext returns data in cp1250 (on win7 witch czech national environment) even if all texts are now UTF-8 and catalog texts too. I did try to create one brand new in UTF-8 from beginning, restarting IIS7.5, but still getting wrong charset (not UTF-8 but cp1250). (I am new in win7, on new pc, maybe it is in some php config, mbstring and iconv has set UTF-8 as internal encoding)

Edit:
This is header of my .po file.I generating .mo every time again:

```
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _;gettext;gettext_noop\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ../../../\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n==1) ? 0 : (n>=2 && n<=4) ? 1 : 2;\n"
"X-Poedit-Language: Czech\n"
"X-Poedit-Country: CZECH REPUBLIC\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: utf-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"
```

All codes and html header is now utf-8. What about any IIS chache? But restart of IIS hase no efect.

Do you have any idea what can be wrong?
Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. First time in my live I must use this (normally I am using apache2):

```
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, "UTF-8");
```

On IIS it must be set even if everything else is written and set to UTF-8...

Answer (score 0):

Your `.po` / `.mo` gettext files are probably using the `cp1250` charset.

Try changing that (with POEdit for instance) to UTF-8, recompile the `.mo` files and restart the server.

If that doesn't work, let us know how you're figuring out the output charset, it may be relevant.